# NDK not found in project file

Tags: flutter, dart

### Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'. > NDK at /home/pc84/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle did not have a source.properties filestrong text

Answer (score 0):

first go to  project level gradle

```
=> gradle-wrapper.propeties
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```

then in build.gradle

```
=> in dependencies  change below line 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, Add ndkVersion in `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
   

    ndkVersion '21.4.7075529' // check version depends on your android and  project
```